# Lighttpd, command line arguments to fastcgi process

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm reading the docs for [mod_fastcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI) in lighttpd, it says:

*"bin-path": path to the local FastCGI binary which should be started if no local FastCGI is running*

What if I want to have lighttpd start directly my fastcgi process, and said process is created by a python script?. Something like this:

```
# bang omitted... I need to use python from virtualenv
# File runfastcgi.py
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "atc.settings")
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'runfcgi', ... ])
```

Additionally, I'm using virtualenv, and I have ways of deriving all the paths from the environment, even the path of the python interpreter for the virtualenv... the only problem is that, according to mod_fastcgi documentation, I can only pass the path to a *binary*, so, it seems that I can not do:

```
 bin-path => (env.ATC_VIRTUALENV + 'bin/python' + ' ' + 'runfastcgi.py')
```

Am I wrong? Is there anyway of asking lighttpd to use a virtualenv python to execute a custom runfastcgi.py?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server maintenance, not about programming, and it should go on Serverfault.

Comment: Instead of `execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'runfcgi', ...])` better use `from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi` and 
`runfastcgi(["method=threaded", "daemonize=false"])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out you can put in bin-path the whole command line. They should add that in the documentation.